# C# generic cast

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I have an interface called `IEditor`

```
public interface IEditor<T> 
    where T: SpecialObject
```

`SpecialObject` is an abstract class.

Here´s my problem:

I have a class which inherits from `SpecialObject` and a view which implements this `IEditor` interface

```
public class View : IEditor<Person>
```

Now, I have to check whether View implements `IEditor<SpecialObject>`

```
Boolean isEditor = View is IEditor<SpecialObject>
```

But `IEditor` is always false

Is there any possibility to check if View is `IEditor<SpecialObject>`?

### Edit

I have a method which is called when a closing event is raised.
The views which are passed to this method can implement IEditor, but they also can implement another interface. In example IView

```
  void Closing(object sender, MyEventArgs e)
  {
      if(e.Item is IView)
      {
          // DO some closing tasks

          if(e.Item is IEditor<SpecialObject>)          // always false
          {
              // Do some special tasks
              var editor = e.Item as IEditor<SpecialObject>;

              var storedEditObect = editor.StoredObject;

              // more tasks
          }
      } else if(e.Item is ISomeOtherView)
      {}
  }
```

I have some classes called Person, Address and so on. They all inherits from SpecialObject.
In some case e.Item inherits from IEditor or from IEditor
Because of that, I have to cast to my base class to access the defaut property fields

Comment: Try tu use "as" keyword and check for null. If NOT null it's of desired type.

Comment: @Tigran `is` and `as` have the same underlying mechanism. The issue here is that `IEditor<Person>` does *not* inherit from `IEditor<SpecialObject>`.

Comment: You can add `IEditor` interface that would be base for IEditor<T>. Then you can check `View is IEditor`

Comment: `View` is the name of a type... you can't use it with `is` like this, as that requires a *value*. Do you have a variable of *type* View, for example? A short but complete program demonstrating the problem would be really useful. My guess is that this is a generic variance problem, but it's hard to say at the moment.

Comment: @dlev: correct! my mistake. Even the View is a type and not an object. I read this too fast.

Comment: @jon Skeet I know. It´s not correct, but its only to demonstrate my Problem.
Let´s say I have a local type of View which is also called View

Comment: @Cr3at0rX: It *really* helps if you give accurate examples. Complete ones, preferably. If something is meant to *demonstrate* a point, it helps if it does actually demonstrate it, rather than just being inaccurate syntax...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Create a non-generic base interface. Eg:

```
public interface IEditor {}

public interface IEditor<T> : IEditor ... {}
```

Then check for `IEditor`.

Comment: I usually hate marker interfaces, but this is actually pretty nice. +1!

Comment: unfortunately this won´t work for me, because I also have to cast the view object

Comment: @Cr3at0rX: Cast it to what? Your requirements are very vague at the moment.

Answer (score 11):

Your problem is generic variance. For example, an `IList<MemoryStream>` isn't an `IList<Stream>`.

As of C# 4 you can *potentially* make your interface *covariant* like this:

```
public interface IEditor<out T> where T: SpecialObject
```

At that point, an `IEditor<Person>` *will* be an `IEditor<SpecialObject>` - but that will only work if your interface only uses `T` in an "out" position.

If this is feasible for you, it's probably cleaner in intent than leppie's non-generic base interface - but that's a good alternative when covariance isn't appropriate.

Comment: Unfortunately this also won´t work for me, because T is not only a return type.
Is there any other possibility?

Comment: @Cr3at0rX: Do you understand *why* it won't work for you then? You simply can't use the object as an `IEditor<SpecialObject>` because it would violate type safety to do so. If you can provide a more complete example for what you're trying to do, we may be able to help you more.

Comment: @Cr3at0rX: Okay, so it looks like you could potentially have a covariant base interface with just the "out" parts, and then an interface extending that which *isn't* covariant.